# https not recognized by PHP when lighttpd url.rewrite used

Tags: php, https, lighttpd

I'm deploying a `PHP` website using `lighttpd`. To get nice URLs working, I've put this into the configuration file:

```
url.rewrite = (
    "^/(?!(wp-admin|wp-includes|wp-content))/(.*)" => "/index.php?$1",
)
```

This works well except of the following side effect.

- When I call a path where the regex in `url.rewrite` does **not** match and call `$_SERVER['HTTPS']`, it will return `"on"`.
- When I call a path where the regex matches and call `$_SERVER['HTTPS']`, it will return nothing.

How can I tell PHP that the connection is secure when using `url.rewrite` ?

Answer (score 1):

This solution is a bit inflexible, but it should be fine if you are sure that the connection uses SSL:

```
server.modules += ( "mod_setenv" )
...
setenv.add-environment = (
    "HTTPS" => "on" 
)
```